# Grunt not updating Script Tags in Angularjs App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower, yeoman, grunt-wiredep

I have two Angularjs projects scaffolded using Yeoman. The first project is a library that has been scaffolded with the [Angular Library Generator](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angularjs-library) while the second is a full app scaffolded with [the Yeoman Angular Generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular). I want the App to use the Library so in the App directory I installed the library using Bower:

```
bower install github-id/library-name --save
```

Although the library is not registered with Bower I can still install it with my Github Id and library name. The `bower_components` directory now holds the library and its dependencies but when I run Grunt using `grunt serve` or just `grunt`, the App's `Index.html` file is not being updated with the library, although you can see that other modules such as `lodash`, for example, are there:

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

And if I try to add the library as a script tag manually, `Grunt` subsequently removes any tags that I add.

Can anyone tell me why the tags are not being added?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by looking in the bower.json file of library project in the `bower_components` directory of my app. In the bower.json file, the path given under the "main" field was incorrect. Once this was fixed then the library was added to the `index.html correctly.